# How to multiply a matrix with vector such that each row is multiplied elementwise with this vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have  matrix of dimension 1682 x 36 and a vector of dimension 1 x 36. I want to multiply each row elementwise with this vector 1 x 36.

An example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [2, 1]])
b = np.array([1, 2])

result= np.array([[1, 4],
              [2, 2]])
```

Comment: did you try `a*b`? This is beginner level numpy broadcasting. voting to close.

Comment: yes, i got a mismatch of dimension ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 36)

Comment: Then your shapes that you are mentioning above are not right. Please print the shapes of a and b

Comment: I have ndarray(1686,36) and ndarray(1,36)

Comment: if you have the exact above shapes (after printing a.shape, b.shape) then this issue will not occur. You will broadcast product with `a*b`

Comment: your error is not reproducible, are you sure its due to the product?? please copy paste the code i have added below and run it.. as a dummy example.

Comment: Sorry it was my bad..., it is solved the dimensions were transposed

Comment: no worries, happens sometimes. A quick clue was in your error itself -> `(n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?)` , as you can see, the `k` is the shared axis which was not aligning properly for the broadcasted product.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple `a*b` that should work based on what you have posted in the question -

As an example -

```
a = np.random.random((1686,36))
b = np.random.random((1,36))

output = a*b
output.shape
```

```
(1686, 36)
```

In case the second one is `(36,)` shape then try -

```
a * b[None,:]
```

This should add an additional axis if you are getting shape issues.